# How to get verified reviews of a product in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, model, relationship

I've following data structure,

**Product**

1. id
2. name
3. description

**Product Review**

1. id
2. user_id
3. product_id
4. review
5. rating
6. status (true/false)

Relationship is one to many i.e. one product has many reviews.

What I want is to load all the products with verified reviews(i.e. reviews with status true)

I've tried following,

```
 $products = Product::with('reviews')->get();
```

but when I iterate over `$products` to access reviews like $product->reviews, all the reviews(even status false reviews) are displayed.

Any kind of suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add a closure to the with function to add extra filtering.

```
Product::with([
    'reviews' => function ($query) { $query->where('status', true); }
])->get();
```

---

Another option is to add a filtered relation function to your product model.

```
public function verifyedReviews() {
    return $this->reviews()->where('status', true);
}
```

And now call this function in your with clause.

```
Product::with('verifyedReviews')->get();
```

Comment: Thank you, I've left return inside function. My bad

Comment: Glad I could help. If this solved your problem, consider marking this as the answer so other users might find this as well.

Comment: Of course, It takes 15 minute to be able to accept :D

Answer (score 1):

try this one by using clousre

```
 $products = Product::with(['reviews' => fuction($query) {
        return $query->where('status',true); 
}])->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use **WhereHas()**

Your code would be:

```
$products = Product::whereHas('reviews',function($query){
    return $query->where('status',true);
})->get();
```